# Immutable bit on AIX?

Tags: filesystems, permissions, files, aix, xattr

Under Linux I can:

```
chattr +i SOMEFILE
```

so that even root can't modify the SOMEFILE. Are there any similar solutions for AIX?

Comment: According to [this IBM article on AIX V6.1 security features](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-aix_compliance/index.html?ca=drs-), there is support for immutable files. I don't know how it's done.

Answer (score 1):

The wikipedia page on chattr says: chattr is a command in the Linux operating system that allows a user to set certain attributes on a file residing on many Linux filesystems. chflags is the analogous command on modern BSD systems, including OS X. The commands are similar to the attrib command on DOS, OS/2 and Microsoft Windows. Other Unix systems have no analogous commands; Solaris supports extended file attributes, but there are no user level commands for setting or changing them, and the chatr command in HP-UX, and chattr in AIX have unrelated functions.

Answer (score 0):

At first I thought that ACLs could do the job. But a quick google revealed that the owner and root can (re)set ACLs on AIX.

`chattr` is specific to ex3/ext3 file-systems (and thus specific to Linux) - so I would say - you need a file-system that supports this feature.

A workaround might be using an NFSv4-mount from another server. In that environment root normally is mapped to a different (not privileged) UID.

Comment: Root can reset the immutable bit on Linux too. I don't know anything about AIX ACLs, what is available that's relevant here?

Comment: extended acl's maybe can do something like the "immuntable bit/flag" under other OSes, but I don't know how.

Comment: FileSystem is JFS2

Comment: AIX does support file immutability, but sadly not with the default jfs2/jfs filesystems. The page that Gilles linked to also mentions this partly *Future release of Filesystems should help explicitly support such features*
Currently immutable files are only supported with GPFS, as that is more a property of the filesystem and not of the operating system, See http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-gpfs/index1.html for more details on those GPFS features.

I'd still like to know your use case, as even on linux immutable flag is rarely used.